# Regex match for several similar string formats

Tags: javascript, regex, string

What is the best way to match a set of strings in this format:

- AA99999999       2 fixed characters 8 numbers
- ABC99999999      3 fixed characters 8 numbers
- AD999999999      2 fixed characters 9 numbers

also

- BA999999999       2 fixed characters 9 numbers
- BB99999x999       2 fixed characters 5 numbers 1 character 3 numbers
- BHA-9999#9        4 fixed characters 4 numbers 1 fixed character 1 number
- BHGD99999     4 fixed characters 5 numbers

For the first match I wrote a regex like this

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{8}|([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{9}|[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{8})
```

This works but I have no idea about the second. Is there are regex that will match these formats?

Comment: I would do individual regexes for each and then test each one individually.  if (typea.matches(str) || typeb.matches(str) || ...)

You can create a single regex like you've already done.  You just keep going.  It's pretty hard to read and understand and maintain though

Comment: What do you mean by fixed characters? Starting with `AA`, `ABC` etc or anything from `A-Z`?

Comment: Not getting your question. You wrote a regexp for the first three cases. Just write more atlernatives for the remaining ones.

Comment: that's why i said that works for first three string!! anyway i don't get you solution as well

Comment: I didn't provide a solution, because I don't understand you question. You wrote patterns for three cases, just write four more for the additional cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty hard to tell exactly what you want here, but I've combined them into two regex expressions rather than using 4, because it's faster. I've used either \w or . where you used [a-zA-Z] because, again, it's difficult to tell what you want. Provide more information and I'll modify the answer.

```
\w{2}\d{5}.\d{3}|.{4}\d{4}.?\d
```

Answer (score 0):

They're simply more of the same:

```
([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{9}|([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{5}[a-zA-Z]\d{3}|[a-zA-Z-]{4}[a-zA-Z#]\d)
```

assuming where a `'-'` pops up a `[a-zA-Z-]` is the group of values that can match there and likewise for `[a-zA-Z#]` for the `'#'`

Answer (score 0):

I would take fixed characters to mean that the specification is to have a case where if the first 3 characters are ABC followed by 8 numbers instead of widlcard letters in which case the patterns for each case would be as follows:

```
AA99999999 2 fixed characters 8 numbers
    AA\d{8}
AD999999999 2 fixed characters 9 numbers
    AD\d{9}
ABC99999999 3 fixed characters 8 numbers
    ABC\d{8}
also
    BA999999999 2 fixed characters 9 numbers
BA\d{9}
    BB99999x999 2 fixed characters 5 numbers 1 character 3 numbers
BB\d{5}x\d{3}
    BHA-9999#9 4 fixed characters 4 numbers 1 fixed character 1 number
BHA-\d{4}#\d
    BHGD99999 4 fixed characters 5 numbers
BHGD\d{5}

var patt1 = /^\w\w[\w\d]{1}[\d\w-]{1}\d{2}[\d\w]{1,4}[\d#]{1}\d+$/;
```

If this is the case you will need to either put each of these in as alternatives or do some logic matching or iterate through each of them to test until a match is found.

Or do you mean capital letters instead of fixed characters?

Maybe you could play with this fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/shotgundriver/r812c00v/6/

Is this a homework problem or real world?

Comment: the regex you gave match any string pattern

Comment: haven't really given a regex .. or rather have given the makings of the set of them. Awaiting clarification on the question definition of 'fixed character' but thought worth sharing the fiddle as it allows to play with the regexes mentioned here etc. each of those patterns will work against the specific pattern described in words ( worth adding the start and end string anchors to be more specific eg first pattern = /^AA\\d{8}$/; .. pretty sure that pattern will not match all of the other test cases provided.